# Jenkins pipeline get repository name on scm change

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 10 git repositories configured in Jenkins pipeline job and included polling on scm change. Now on SCM change I wanted to know in which repository a change has been made.

Using groovy **currentBuild.changeSets** I am able to get author name, commit message and affectedFiles but I am not able to find how to get repository name or url.